# Attaching a view page display to a tab in a content type?

Tags: views, theming, routes

I've built a CSV exporter by heavily modifying a template file from Views Bonus Pack's CSV feed Views plugin that formats all the content in a particular view exactly how I want it.

Now, I just need to find some way of integrating it into the work flow. Ideally, on each "projectsheet" content-type node, there would be 3 tabs for admins: View, Edit, Export.

The exporter feed is attached to a Page display that's part of the view. If I set that page's path to something like "node/%/export", it usurps the default display of that node and the node becomes that view.

**How do I create a new tab, to which a Views Page display is attached, that's visible only in a certain content type and doesn't take over the default view of that content type?**

I'm using Drupal 6 and the Views UI; considering everything I've done is in Views UI as a template for Views Bonus Pack, I'd really like to not code a new module to achieve this (i.e., just use Views UI to accomplish it if possible).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *Page settings* section of the Page display of your view:

Path: node/%/export
Menu: Menu tab, Title: Export

You'll probably have an argument in your view already. In that argument's configuration:

Validator: Node
Node type: projectsheet (or whatever node types to display tab for)

Comment: That worked! I think that's more-or-less what I had; I think I had to change some of the values in the argument's config. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem.

I wrote a simple module "Views node access" for d7 which allows you to bind a view page to a specified node type. The code is in 
http://drupal.org/sandbox/cezaryrk/1244456

It is independent from the argument settings.

Comment: This is a D6 question; should have clarified that...